# App is crashing after updating to latest android support library version 22.2, however it is working on version 21 +

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

Recently, I have updated my app from API version 21 to 22 including their support libraries in Android Studio. But after this app started crashing, what to do now?

Comment: Now, you post the error log.

Comment: can you post your logcat output?

Comment: By  the way its woking now, thanks to all for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight up answer:

> Just go back to your working API version

Elaboration: Because your question is so open ended, there are a variety of possible reasons. Of course things are going to break when you switch API versions. You need to read up on the changes in the new version, especially depreciated methods, and fix those errors in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that much reputation to upvote your answer (new here).

Comment: @AbhimanyuRaj no problem you can still click the tick. protip: this increases your credibility too

Answer (score -1):

add in your theme

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Comment: How does this help unless you knew the specific problem?

Comment: because I had a same issue while upgrading to 22, the AppComat 22.2.0 use AppComatActivity, which requires a NoActionBar Theme